# NoSQL duplicate counting and removing

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have gathered around 10k of tweets from one music event. As you can imagine there are many retweets. To do proper anlysis I want to count each retwet, and later delete retweets or remove duplicates. I couldn't find a way how to do it in NoSQL, so asking here for help and advice. Using MongoDB and Robomongo GUI client.

And by duplicates I mean entries with identical text fields

Collections consist in this type of structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53cd28ea51f4fbe9f6e04798"),
    "name" : "Positivus Festival",
    "screenName" : "positivus",
    "text" : "RT @Valsts_policija: Tuvojas @positivus , tādēļ esam sagatavojuši septiņus drošības ieteikumus patīkamai atpūtai #Positivus110 http://t.co/…",
    "time" : 1405606042.803368
}
```

Comment: So what would a duplicate look like? same text exactly?

Comment: yes, text fields are identical. Failes to mention that, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the MongoDB aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

In this case, I believe the following code will print out all duplicate tweets and their total number:

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
       {$group : { _id: "$text" ,  count : { $sum: 1}}},
       {$match : { count : { $gt : 1 } }} ])
```

You should see something like this as a result:

```
{
    "_id" : "RT @Valsts_policija: Tuvojas @positivus , tādēļ esam sagatavojuši septiņus drošības ieteikumus patīkamai atpūtai #Positivus110 http://t.co/…",
    "count" : 2
}
```

Assuming there were 2 tweets with that identical text.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly in mongoDB , just to fetch all unique value for a specific field ("In Your Case Tweet TEXT") .

Try the command

```
db.collection.distinct('text')
```

you will got all the tweet with distinct text :)

Comment: it is great, almost what i need to. This does retuns all unique tweets, but how to reverse it so it returns only duplicated tweets?